# Does Java support Julian calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

Oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/calendar.doc.html states that Java supports 3 calendar systems: Gregorian, Japanese Imperial and Thai Buddhist. Does Java support Julian calendar?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html Julian calendar is supported within GregorianCalendar class.

Comment: AFAIK, The Julian Calendar is only used for religious purposes today.  Historically some countries used it until less than a century ago.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: AFAIK, it is still being used by some community.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it does.

From the doc of GregorianCalendar:

> GregorianCalendar is a hybrid calendar that supports both the Julian
>   and Gregorian calendar systems with the support of a single
>   discontinuity, which corresponds by default to the Gregorian date when
>   the Gregorian calendar was instituted (October 15, 1582 in some
>   countries, later in others). The cutover date may be changed by the
>   caller by calling setGregorianChange().

Use `setGregorianChange` to change it.

> public void setGregorianChange(Date date) Sets the GregorianCalendar
>   change date. This is the point when the switch from Julian dates to
>   Gregorian dates occurred. Default is October 15, 1582 (Gregorian).
>   Previous to this, dates will be in the Julian calendar. To obtain a
>   pure Julian calendar, set the change date to Date(Long.MAX_VALUE). To
>   obtain a pure Gregorian calendar, set the change date to
>   Date(Long.MIN_VALUE).

Answer (score 2):

The standard [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class might not, but the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's not in java.* :

[JulianCalendar javadoc](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/util/calendar/JulianCalendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

People don't use java.util.Calendar a lot. In fact, it will be succeeded soon by what is now already in a library called 'joda time', when [JSR-310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) finishes. [Joda Time also has a Julian calendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_julian.html).

Just add joda-time to your project as a dependency and away you go.