# Problem converting milliseconds since epoch to calendar date before 1582

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to get the date from elasticsearch stored as 14-May-1581 in java. I have the date from elasticsearch in milliseconds (-12264134400000). While converting to date in Java, the date is calculated wrong. I know that this is related with the Georgian and Julian calendar but am not able to find a solution for it. The code I'm using is simply:

```
Date dt = new Date(-12264134400000L);
```

The above gives 04-May-1581 instead of 14-May-1581.

To give more details, I have many such dates entered in the Oracle database which get moved to Elasticsearch. The way I'm getting date from Elasticsearch is in milliseconds (This is how it is reading from lucene index. Consider this as a constraint). So I want to convert milliseconds back into the original date so that I can compare it with another date. So if elasticsearch converted 14-May-1581 into -12264134400000, I want 14-May-1581 back.

Comment: That's before the gregorian calendar came into force. You're just expecting the wrong results.

Comment: True, but I have dates that are such in the database. I just need to get those dates back from milliseconds someway in Java.

Comment: For me it seems about right. From Wiki about gregorian calendar: "To deal with the 10 days' difference (between calendar and reality) that this drift had already reached, the date was advanced so that 4 October 1582 was followed by 15 October 1582" - probably that's why there is 10 days diff in your results.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569542/does-java-support-julian-calendar) question and the related answer.

Comment: Please tell us what you're doing with the `Date` after creating it. A `Date` is *just* an instant in time - converting it to a date with years/months/days requires additional operations. (I'd avoid using `dt.toString()` for various reasons.) The answer here will depend on what you want to do with it.

Comment: How do you convert to local date? `java.util.Date` just keeps instant from specific point of time, converting it do date/time will depend on calendar, timezone etc.

Comment: I'm fascinated that your Kibana instance has such old events persisted!

Comment: @BrianAgnew suppose you have a database of historical events...

Comment: "I want 14-May-1581 back" - as a string? As something else? Again, more detail is required. Ideally, provide some code showing what you're doing with the date.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - granted. Just not the sort of scenario I'd expect Kibana to be used for (perhaps that simply reflects my Kibana experience)

Comment: @JonSkeet. It doesn't really matter Date or String. Once the right value is achieved it can be formatted to anything.

Comment: But it absolutely *does* matter. You're already getting the right value in `Date` - it's only how you're *viewing* that value that's giving you the wrong results. It's the conversion of `Date` into a form that has years/months/days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `java.time` package, introduced in Java 8:

```
LocalDate date = 
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

this gives expected results

Comment: Seems right for a couple of values. Let me test and I'll update.

Comment: Note that using the system default time zone may well not be the right approach here - I'd suggest checking that very carefully.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I fail to see why time zone matters in this scenario, which deals with dates only

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: You're converting an instant into a date. An instant may fall on different dates depending on the time zone. For example, 10 hours ago it was May 20th in the UK but May 19th in the US.

Comment: @JonSkeet, so the problem is not specific to system default time zone. the problem is needing to set time zone in this scenario

Comment: @SharonBenAsher: It's a matter of working out which time zone should be used, yes - but "the system default time zone" is rarely a good answer for that. (It's possible, but I'd say it's unlikely.) That's why I suggested it should be checked very carefully.

Comment: Please note that this probably doesn’t give you the *correct* date for the millisecond value, but as long as it gives the *asker’s expected* value, I still recommend it. A likely explanation would be that java.time was used for generating the millisecond value, so this makes the process reversible. java.time uses the [*Proleptic Gregorian calendar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar), which doesn’t agree with the dates real people used in 1581 and earlier (the story is much longer).

Comment: @OleV.V., the link you provided, states: "The proleptic Gregorian calendar is explicitly required for all dates before 1582 by ISO 8601:2004 (clause 4.3.2.1 The Gregorian calendar) if the partners to information exchange agree." this reads to me that using `java.time` is indeed the correct value for usage by digital system.

Answer (score 1):

> The way I'm getting date from Elasticsearch is in milliseconds (This is how it is reading from lucene index. Consider this as a constraint).

I would reassess the necessity of the constraint you mention. Who is imposing that, and why?

Working with instants in milliseconds since or until the [Unix epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) is acceptable for points in time after (roughly) 1950, but you are setting yourself up for a host of problems by converting historical dates from the sixteenth century to milliseconds; including but not limited to figuring out which time zone to use, and how to make sure the same time zone is used on both the side that converts your dates to milliseconds, and the side that converts them back into dates. How is ElasticSearch converting your date into a milliseconds timestamp?

There is also the very real risk that the software stack you using was never tested with historical dates in timestamp-like fields intended for recent and current instants in time.

If you need an intermediate format to transmit these dates, use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) calendar dates in a `YYYY-MM-DD` of `YYYYMMDD` string notation. This at least means that sorting them works out of the box.

For working with historical dates in Java, start with the [`java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) introduced in Java 8 (as mentioned by @sharon-ben-asher).

Comment: In other words: Tracking moments from half a millennium ago is pointless, and doing so in milliseconds is even sillier.